# Using AES_ENCRYPT CBC mode with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo, aes

I am able to use MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()` function in MySQL itself.

Here are the steps I used to enable that:

1) Add the following lines to /etc/my.cnf to use CBC mode

```
[mysqld]
block_encryption_mode=aes-256-cbc
```

2) Restart MySQL
3) Check it is working in MySQL:

```
SELECT @@session.block_encryption_mode;
```

4) Create random IV:

```
SELECT RANDOM_BYTES(16);
```

5) Store the IV in a safe place and set @iv in MySQL

```
SET @iv = 'output from above'
```

6) Test inserting data in MySQL

```
UPDATE some_table
SET column_name = HEX(AES_ENCRYPT("data here", 'enc key here', @iv))
WHERE id=1;
```

That works fine.  I can update columns with tha

However, when I try to add data from PHP PDO, I get the following error:

```
HY000 1882 The initialization vector supplied to aes_encrypt is too short. Must be at least 16 bytes long
```

Here is a the query:

```
UPDATE session_data SET
    session_url=:session_url,
    session_password=:HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(:session_password), :enc_key, @iv),
    session_creation_datetime=now()
    WHERE session_id=:session_id
```

The query works fine without AES_ENCRYPT().  I suspect that using **@iv** in the PHP PDO query is the problem.

Does anyone know if this is true and whether there is another way to access @iv in MySQL from PHP?

Comment: How do you set @iv from the php code? Why don't you use the random_bytes function directly with aes_encrypt?

Comment: The reason that I would not use the RANDOM_BYTES function is because that would not store the IV which is needed to decrypt the column data.